# Email's table width is breaking in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

My HTML email template is displaying correctly without major problems in Gmail, Yahoo, Apple Mail and iOS Mail. Outlook however is a horrifying mess and I can't for the life of me figure out what I've done wrong?

The problem is every table in my layout stretches to 100% despite me setting it to 600px for the container.

Can anyone help me figure out how to keep everything in the 600px container?

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Introducing Neck Firming Complex</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p{  
    line-height:1.8 !important;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
img,a img{
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.plusList{
    list-style-image:url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/a4f776c6-7a65-403f-ae36-3345646d9b79.png);
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
/*styling for objects with screen size less than 480px; */
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote { 
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Ariel, sans-serif;
}
table {
    /* All tables are 100% width */
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:480px !important;
    border-style: none !important;
}
.footer {
    /* Each footer column in this case should occupy 100% width  and 4% is allowed for email client padding*/
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.responsiveImage {
    /* Container for each image now specifying full width */
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.responsiveContent {
    /* Content in catalog  occupying full width of cell */
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align:center!important;
    margin:0 auto!important;
}
.responsiveHide{
    display:none;
}
.socialTop{
    display:none;   
}
.btn{
    padding:10px 60px !important;
}

}
</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #F2F2F2;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
<table width="100%"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><table width="600px"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;max-width:600px;">
          <!-- Main Wrapper Table with initial width set to 600px -->
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#FFF;max-width:600px;"><table width="292" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;" class="responsiveHide">
                  <!-- First header column with Logo -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="bottom" style="font-size: 9px; color:#7d868c; text-align:left; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">It’s not all about the face – a surprising way to look younger</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="responsiveContent" width="292" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; text-align:right">
                  <!-- Second header column with social media -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="font-size: 9px; color:#7d868c; text-align:right; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="#" style="color:#7d868c;">View this email in your browse</a>r</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;background-color:#84cace;" height="4"><table width="100%" align="left"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;background-color:#84cace;" height="4"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/34c8e5c0-4ecc-4a4d-b2d2-d58f42426bda.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""/></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:#FFF;">
              <td align="center" style="max-width:600px;"><table width="290" align="left" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" class="responsiveContent">
                  <!-- First header column with Logo -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-size: 13px; color:#7d868c; text-align:left; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" class="responsiveContent"><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/5083d1e0-d14d-4025-8316-ffc7c24b3675.png" width="252" height="57" alt="Lifeline Skin Care" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <table width="290" height="57" align="left" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="text-align:right" class="socialContent">
                  <!-- Second header column with social media -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="socialTop">
                      <td align="right" valign="top" style="font-size: 13px; color:#7d868c; text-align:right; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width:100%;">
                      <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="112" class="socialTop">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="28"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LifelineSkincare"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/b90f4ac4-16cd-49c1-88e2-da7703297bdc.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Like us on Facebook" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28"><a href="https://twitter.com/LifelineSkin"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/61ac3d96-25a7-4767-b585-d6ef1e8429d0.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Follow us on Twitter" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28"><a href="https://instagram.com/lifelineskin/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/bf49f5a2-42d7-471f-96aa-1f96110d4d5b.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Love us on Instagram" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/lifelinesc/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/8dd75190-e598-4a0a-90e1-c145467f53d1.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Follow us on Pinterest" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>                     
                 </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right" valign="bottom" class="responsiveContent" style="font-size: 13px; color:#7d868c; text-align:right; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsiveContent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-size: 13px; color:#7d868c; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/" style="font-size: 10px; color:#7d868c; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">HOME</a> | <a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/press/"  style="font-size: 10px; color:#7d868c; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">PRESS</a> | <a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/stem-cell-skin-cream-sample/"  style="font-size: 10px; color:#7d868c; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">REQUEST A SAMPLE</a> | <a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/buy.html" style="font-size: 10px; color:#84cace; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;">SHOP</a> </span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <td><table width="100%" align="center"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsiveImage" style="max-width:600px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/buy/neck-firming-complex.html"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/f3edc992-b5cf-4222-96fe-2e404d19187e.jpg"  width="600" style="max-width: 600px;border:0;" alt="Introducing Neck Firming Complex
" class="responsiveImage"/></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <!-- HTML Spacer row -->
              <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;background-color:#84cace;" height="10"><table width="100%" align="left"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="max-width:600px;font-size: 0; line-height: 0;background-color:#84cace;" height="10"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/34c8e5c0-4ecc-4a4d-b2d2-d58f42426bda.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""/></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <td style="background-color:#FFF;"><table width="100%"  align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
              </tr>               
                  <tr> 
                    <!-- Row container for Content -->
                    <td align="left" style="text-align:left; padding:10px 20px 0px 20px;max-width:600px;" >
                    <h1 style="font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:14px; color:#7d868c;">Lifeline Skin Care introduces its newest age-defying beauty product&hellip;<br>
<span style="font-size:24px; color:#84cace;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
Neck Firming Complex</span></h1>
<hr size="1" color="#84cace" noshade style="display: block; height: 1px; border: 1px solid #84cace; line-height:125%;" />
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/0e17c58f-8b1a-4484-a64f-8ca9928fed43.jpg" width="188" height="187" hspace="10" align="right" alt="Neck Firming Complex" style="float:right;border:0;" class="responsiveHide"/></a>Is your neck pre-maturely aging you? Do you avoid low-cut blouses and dresses because you’re ashamed of the blotchiness, the creases and wrinkles, the loose and sagging skin of your neck and décolleté?  Well, you can kiss those scarves and high-neck shirts goodbye! Lifeline has created a remarkably effective Neck Firming Complex to renew the look and feel of your most delicate skin.</p>
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Visibly smooth away wrinkles and promote elasticity of the neck and décolleté with this deeply hydrating and restorative complex.</p>
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">This powerful formula, using peptides derived from non-embryonic stem cells, along with highly potent specialized ingredients, including dynamic moisturizers, Lifeline’s Neck Firming Complex restores the appearance of firmer, smoother, and younger looking neck, while also providing a healthy looking and even skin tone.</p>
<hr size="1" color="#84cace" noshade style="display: block; height: 1px; border: 1px solid #84cace;" />
<p style="font-size:14px; color:#84cace; font-weight:bold;">Results you’ll see when you use Neck Firming Complex by Lifeline Skin Care:</p>
</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="text-align:left; padding:10px 20px 0px 20px; "><table width="140" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="responsiveContent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="responsiveContent"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/1c5e8ba1-fbd4-46f9-9372-6003aad5f0d7.jpg" width="129" height="167" alt="Neck Firming Complex" style="border:0;"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table width="392" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="responsiveContent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="responsiveContent"><ul class="plusList" style="list-style-type:square;">
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong>Visibly Firms, lifts and tightens delicate skin</strong></li>
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong> Balances Skin Tone</strong></li>
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong> Minimizes discoloration and redness of skin for a
          more even looking tone          </strong></li>
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong>Supports cell renewal</strong></li>
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong> Boosts Collagen Production</strong></li>
        <li style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong> Minimizes the appearance of fine line and creases</strong></li>
      </ul></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; padding:10px 20px 0px 20px; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <hr size="1" color="#84cace" noshade style="clear:both; display: block; height: 1px; border: 1px solid #84cace;" />
<p style="font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; color:#7d868c; line-height:125%; text-align:left; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">The next time you put on that stunning V-neck top, you’ll be proud to stick your neck out amongst the crowd.  And let’s face it…when you look good, you feel great!</p>
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: separate !important; border: 2px none #84cace;border-radius: 5px;background-color: #84cace; margin:0 auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="padding:16px;"><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/buy.html" class="btn" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;padding:10px 80px;">SHOP NOW &raquo;</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
&nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>               
              <td><table width="100%" align="left"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="responsiveImage" style="max-width:600px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.lifelineskincare.com/customer-service/lifeline-skin-care-autodelivery"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/148283d9-257f-4cb5-b1fc-9878edf34cc1.jpg" width="600" style="max-width:600px;border:0;" alt="Save time and money with Auto-Ship" class="responsiveImage"/></a></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" height="60px" style="padding:20px;background-color:#FFF;max-width:600px;">
              <table class="socialBtm" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="112" style="width:112px !important;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="28" style="width:28px !important;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/LifelineSkincare"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/b90f4ac4-16cd-49c1-88e2-da7703297bdc.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Like us on Facebook" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28" style="width:28px !important;"><a href="https://twitter.com/LifelineSkin"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/61ac3d96-25a7-4767-b585-d6ef1e8429d0.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Follow us on Twitter" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28" style="width:28px !important;"><a href="https://instagram.com/lifelineskin/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/bf49f5a2-42d7-471f-96aa-1f96110d4d5b.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Love us on Instagram" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
      <td width="28" style="width:28px !important;"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/lifelinesc/"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/2e923957e144aaa5ad2a794ad/images/8dd75190-e598-4a0a-90e1-c145467f53d1.png" width="24" height="24" alt="Follow us on Pinterest" style="border:0;"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
              <p style="font-size: 10px; font-style: normal; color:#84cace; line-height:125%; text-align:center; font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Copyright © 2015 Lifeline Skin Care. All Rights Reserved.</p></td>
            </tr>            
          </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `width="600px"` instead of `width="600"` but most likely you should put the width on the table instead of the cell

Comment: Your css has a lot of !important properties. !important should be used only when you are trying to override style for an element and there is no other way out except using !important. Try to get rid of them if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issues is this:

```
table width="100%"
```

In this case, the parent container is literally the body with no width set. You should set the width of 600px on the table itself.

Comment: If so, this question is a simple error question and should be closed so it can be auto deleted instead of getting an accepted answer, where it would not be auto deleted

Answer (score 0):

You should find this to work:

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding :0;">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
  <td>
    <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
       <td>
```

I've left out your custom markup, but this will give you the general idea.